# PHP usort 2 dimensional array not working (sort by integer)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array: `$attachments = array();`

Which is populated like this:

```
if (have_rows('attachments_items')):
       while ( have_rows('attachments_items') ) : the_row();
                       $attachment_id = get_sub_field('fileattachment',false);
                       $year = get_sub_field('year',false);
                       if(is_null($year) || $year == 0){
                           $year=2018;
                       }
                   
                       $attachments[$i]['year'] = (int)$year;
                       $attachments[$i]['id'] = $attachment_id;
                       $i++;
      endwhile;
endif;
```

I want to sort it by year so I tried that:

```
usort($attachments,function($first,$second){
    return $first->year < $second->year;
});
```

But its not working:

**Before**

> unsorted:Array (
> [0] => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 14689 )
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzbDg.png)
> => Array ( [year] => 2017 [id] => 14690 )
> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MztFN.png) => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 14688 )
> [3] => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 14687 ) .....)

[image]

**After**

> sorted:Array (
> [0] => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 14689 )
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzbDg.png)
> => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 16323 )
> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MztFN.png) => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 21545 )
>
> [3] => Array ( [year] => 2017 [id] => 14690 )
>
> [4] => Array ( [year] => 2018 [id] => 12711 )
> .....)

[image]

Comment: And why it is not working? Years are sorted

Comment: @u_mulder it is not sorted. please check updated post.

Comment: If you had error reporting turned on you would notice the messages `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'year' of non-object in...` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to sort arrays but you are using the fields as object properties `$first->year`.

Try using

```
usort($attachments, function ($first, $second) {
    return $first["year"] < $second["year"];
});

print_r($attachments);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cLGm6)